# How do I create a cross-reference table in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a table of values like so in Excel:

```
Col1 Col2
---- ----
 a    1
 b    2
 c    3
 d    1
 e    1
 f    2
```

I want the resulting cross reference table to be created based on some function(s):

```
   NewCol1     NewCol2
   -------     -------
      1        a, d, e
      2        b, f
      3        c
```

How would I do that?  Is it possible?

Comment: It will take vba coding if you do not want helper columns with excel 2016 as it does not have TEXTJOIN.  See [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56858571/merge-values-of-column-b-based-on-common-values-on-column-a) for a TEXTJOINIFS() UDF

Comment: What have you tried to do?

Answer (score 1):

Put your cursor anywhere in your table then use Data>Get & Transform Data>From Table/Range. If you have an earlier version of Excel, this may be accessible via the Power Query Add-In.

The Power Query Editor should open and show you this:

[image]

Select Col2 by clicking the header and use Home>Transform>Group By, like this:

[image]

When you click OK, you will see that Summing Col1 causes an Error:

[image]

Use Home>Query>Advanced Editor, so that you see this:

[image]

Now change the part that says this:

```
List.Sum([Col1])
```

To this:

```
Text.Combine([Col1],", ")
```

So that you have this:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Col1", type text}, {"Col2", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Col2"}, {{"Col1", each Text.Combine([Col1],", "), type text}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

When you click OK you will get the results you want:

[image]

Now you can use Home>Close & Load to load the results into your workbook. When new data are added to the source table, just right-click the table in the workbook and choose "Refresh" to run the transformation again.